# Excel VBA Goto specific row number then return values to the right

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bit of a different request. I'm trying to find a solution, I need VBA code to go to a specific Row number, and then to return values on that particular row in a Dialog box. I have a bit of a workaround in so much as I have each cell in Column A matching the relevant Row by using =Row(), and then returning the cells to right of that, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution, and eliminate the extra column and only look for the row number?
cheers
anq

Comment: Is your VBA a `Sub` or a `Function`?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @EganWolf My code is  
`txtCompany.Value = Application.VLookup("R" & txtLineNumber.Value, Sheets("data").Range("A2:J10000"), 2, 0)` 
R is the text I have had to put at the start of the line as Vlookup doesn't like searching for numbers (for me anyway) in my spreadsheet row 1700 is listed at R1700 in column A

Answer (score 1):

**Function**
Use `Application.Caller.Row` to get the row. This example messages the value from column 1 for the row that contains the cell which contains the formula calling this function.

`MsgBox(ws.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 1))`

**Macro**
Loop through your rows and process what you need. Here's an example that loops and messages the value in column 1.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim iRow As Integer
'You starting row in the actual sheet
iRow = 1
Dim iEndRow As Integer
'Set this.
iEndRow = 100


For iRow = 1 To iEndRow Step 1
    'loop through each row.
    'message what's in column 1 for this row.
    MsgBox (ws.Cells(iRow, 1))
Next iRow
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, however For 

`iRow To iEndRow Step 1`

comes up as Syntax error

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you need to provide the value to start with in the loop. Try the edited answer.

Comment: Cheers Michael, I'll give it a shot